# Is there any way to set the email signature from my own app?

Tags: ios, iphone, email, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My Requirement is to set the email signature at run time. I have used MFMailComposeviewcontroller to send the mail but not able to open the directly signature setting windows from an App.

Answer (score 0):

You have no direct access to the signature. The best you can do is to set some message body text (`setMessageBody:isHTML:`), but another signature may be added after that - you can't tell.